# Refresh page content not images

Tags: javascript, ajax

Looking for a method to refresh a page onclick but not the images of that page, just text content. Is this done by doing so without refreshing cache? is it even possible? I have tried refreshing the whole page using this method in my javascript:

```
<script>
$(".second").pageslide({ direction: "left", cratel: true, onClick="history.go(0)" });
</script>
```

I have had zero luck, any direction would be appreciated. I am not sure if this would be a valid question or not and if so please let me know. I am only new to stackoverflow.

Comment: cache the images - they will load faster for the user. Either that or fetch the text, and replace the contents of the DIV you want to have replaced

Comment: You better consider AngularJS for your requirement. Its a cake walk for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but still it depends on the contents and the images that how much they are related to each other. If images are not part of the text contents, then it can be done easily.

Lets suppose you have 4 section of text contents A, B, C and D , then using JQuery ajax method asynchronously you can reload only the four text contents easily.

What you have to do is to give unique ids to text contents like

```
<div id="a">text contents for A goes here</div>
<div id="b">text contents for B goes here</div>
<div id="c">text contents for C goes here</div>
<div id="D">text contents for D goes here</div>
```

Now using [JQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) feature , you can load those contents by an onClick event or as you want.

After each contents are returned by each respective ajax call then you can place them in desired text contents place using below JQuery method

```
$("a").html("your returned text contents for a");
...
...
```

I hope this will help you.

Thank you